# Определить время работы алгоритма

Tags: java, алгоритм, профилирование

Решал задание: найти в массиве строк ту, в которой меньшее количество повторяющихся символов; но когда понадобилось определить скорость работы, запутался. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться, каково время работы данной реализации, и главное, **почему**? Спасибо.

```
public String getLessRepeatChars(@NotNull final String[] src) {
    if (src.length == 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    String result = src[0];
    int tmp = getAmountDifferentCharsIn(src[0]);
    for (int i = 1; i < src.length; i++) {
        final int amount = getAmountDifferentCharsIn(src[i]);
        if (tmp > amount) {
            tmp = amount;
            result = src[i];
        }
    }
    return result;
}

private int getAmountRepeatCharsIn(@NotNull final String s) {
    final Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (Character c : s.toCharArray()) {
        Integer amount = map.get(c);
        if (amount == null) {
            map.put(c, 1);
        } else {
            map.replace(c, ++amount);
        }
    }

    int result = 0;
    for (Integer val : map.values()) {
        if (val > result) result = val;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Буду признателен конструктивной критике по реализации, особенно в плане производительности.

Comment: используйте лучше [getOrDefault](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#getOrDefault-java.lang.Object-V-) и не используйте обертку

Comment: Вам нужна асимптотика или конкретное время работы ( в милисекундах, например)?

Comment: @Alexander Veselov отношение роста времени работы к колличеству элементов, типо O(?) или даже не столько ответ сколько как он получился.

Comment: Что такое `getAmountDifferentCharsIn` и где используется `getAmountRepeatCharsIn` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Метод getAmountRepeatCharsIn

Возьмем за `n` длину строки `s`.
Сначала происходит подсчет всех символов в строке — происходит это за линейное время.
Затем ищется максимальное значение — это тоже происходит за линейное время.
Т.е функция getAmountRepeatCharsIn работает за `O(n)`.

### Метод getLessRepeatChars

Возьмем за m количество строк в массиве `src`. Выполняется проход по всем строкам, в каждой итерации которого вызывается `getAmountRepeatCharsIn`. Т.е. время работы всего алгоритма будет `O(m*n)`, где m и n — это ***выше написано***. (Чтобы быть точнее, то за n наверное даже стоит взять наибольшее из всех длин).
Ну личное мое мнение, что асимптотически этот алгоритм улучшить нельзя, потому что как минимум нужно прочитать всю информацию массива, что уже займет `O(m*n)`.
 Единственное, можно улучшить алгоритм в плане исправлений константных операций. (ну например, не обязательно каждый раз копировать строку, чтоб вернуть её. Можно хранить просто индекс, а потом вернуть нужную строку исходя из индекса).

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста ещё момент если getAmountRepeatCharsIn делает сначала подсчёт символов в строке за линейное время это O(n) и ещё раз за ищется за O(n) максимальное значение разве это в результате не даёт O(2n) ?

Comment: n и 2n растут с одинаковой скоростью. Эту двойку "съедает" буква О. Допустим пример: есть алгоритм, который делает какую-то операцию за линейное время, а затем ещё что-то за квадратичное; временная сложность этого алгоритма будет O(n^2), несмотря на то, что хотелось бы сказать O(n + n^2). В оценке асимптотической сложности всегда пишется наиболее быстро растущая функция